# mpirun: one process terminates but prints no core dump

Tags: crash, fortran, mpi, fortran90, coredump

Folks, I am stumbling upon quite a weird issue. I am running a job with mpirun command:

```
   mpirun -np 4 ~/opt/stuff/OSMC
```

Sometimes (the execution depends on a number of random values) one of the four processes dies:

```
  Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
  OSMC               000000000050B54D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
  OSMC               000000000050A055  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
  OSMC               00000000004BA320  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
  OSMC               000000000047976F  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
  OSMC               0000000000479B72  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
  OSMC               000000000043B7DC  mpi_m_mp_exchange         306  mpi_m.f90
  OSMC               0000000000430880  mpi_m_mp_coagulat          85  mpi_m.f90
  OSMC               000000000041304B  op_m_mp_op_run_            81  op_m.f90
  OSMC               000000000040FF22  osmc_m_mp_run_            543  OSMC_m.f90
  OSMC               000000000040FD09  MAIN__                     28  OSMC_m.f90
  OSMC               000000000040FC4C  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
  libc.so.6          000000362081ED5D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
  OSMC               000000000040FB49  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mpirun has exited due to process rank 1 with PID 28468 on
  node rcfen04 exiting without calling "finalize". This may
  have caused other processes in the application to be
  terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here).
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The system prints no core dump, so I have no more informations apart of this short summary. I gave a look in mpi_m.f90 line 306, where an existing array is set to 0.
The system should be able to print a core dump file, since:

```
  [user@host path]$ ulimit -a
  core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
  ...
```

This is the piece of code that is reported in the short summary:

```
  module mpi_m
    implicit none
    ...
    real(wp),allocatable :: part(:,:) ! ARRAY DECLARATION
    ...
    allocate( part_(pdim,is_:ie_) )   ! ARRAY ALLOCATION
    ...
    subroutine exchanger_compute_bij(ierr,msg)
    implicit none
    ...
    part = 0.0_wp                     ! HERE CODE CRASHES
    ...
    end subroutine
    ...
  end module
```

Nothing seems wrong to me. The incriminated instruction is a fortran vector operation, should be fine. It crashes even when I compile with bound checking.

How can I determine the reason for this sudden crash? I hoped a core dump file, given to Totalview or some other debugger, could have helped..

Comment: Are you sure the "existing array" that is set to 0 actually exists? Sounds like according to some logic, this array was never allocated (or perhaps allocated with a smaller size than you want). So when it gets to this line of code, it's trying to access out-of-bounds memory. You need to track this array through your code to find out more.

Comment: What do you expect a core dump to do for you? I recommend you go through the usual debugging practice. Compile with bounds checking and optimizations off, and so on.

Comment: I answer to your comments adding infos in the post. Thank you all. My great problem is lack of information. I just see that it terminates and gives short summary. No more.

Comment: Is your `allocate` statement reproduced correctly here? There is a trailing underscore in the array name. If the program crashes in the `part = 0.0_wp` statement, it could be that your MPI processes use more memory than the sum of the available physical memory and swap on node `rcfen04`.

Comment: Dear, I discovered the problem. It was not really related to that declaration (the underscore is a typo). It was related with a poorly written conditional construct that caused the execution of the wrong subroutine. Sorry for bothering.
I just add a question: the code was not printing any error code, until I explicitly set the array boundaries in that line, as
      part(1:x,1:y) = 0.0_wp
In that case the code complained that the array was not allocated, so it was crashing. How can i let the code always print an error message for every possible mistake? I am using the Intel fortran compiler